# Changing file ownership with chown

Tags: chown

I'm currently logged in as `root`, and I want to switch ownership of files to the `xyz` user. How can I do that using chown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chown xyz file1 file2 file3` for single files and directories

`chown -R xyz dir1` for recursive directories

Comment: I would politely add to this: `man chown`. Especially for such simple and basic Unix commands. That said, if the proper usage of `chown` is unknown to you and you have root access, I would seriously consider reading a more thorough beginner's guide to Unix before you accidentally make a mistake you could regret!